# When overlaying two identically-sized images, one is offset

Tags: .net, vb.net, image, bitmap, gdi+

I am attempting to create an image by overlaying one on top of another. The code works, but the image I am overlaying seems to be slightly stretched and I can't work out why.

So the code just creates a blank red 24x24 rectangle, then I overlay a 24x24 png file which looks like this:

[image]

What I am expecting is this:

[image]

But I actually get this:

[image]

```
Using backGround As New Bitmap(24, 24, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
        Using g = Graphics.FromImage(backGround)
            Using brush1 As New SolidBrush(Color.Red)
                g.FillRectangle(brush1, 0, 0, 24, 24)
                Using topimage = Image.FromFile("C:\Scratch\ManNoRecords24.png")
                    g.DrawImage(topimage, New Point(0, 0))
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        backGround.Save("C:\Scratch\Emp.png", Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
    End Using
```

Debugger showing the properties of the topImage:

[image]

Comment: In the debugger, check the dimensions of `topimage`. What are they? Is it 24x24 like you expect?

Comment: Yes I checked that it is indeed 24x24

Comment: Is it possible that the png file has an unusual DPI in it?  Does the same thing happen with a different top image?

Comment: @eric - yes you are spot on, the backGround has res of `96`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
g.DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped(topimage, New Rectangle(0, 0, 24, 24))
```

instead, to avoid any scaling of the source image while drawing it. This works but I am actually not quite sure what is wrong with your solution.

From the  [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Graphics.cs,2f0714b9077274ba), `DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped` seems to use `Pixel` as the default unit for the image size and hence ignores the DPI setting of the source image:

```
/// <include file='doc\Graphics.uex' path='docs/doc[@for="Graphics.DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped"]/*' />
/// <devdoc>
/// </devdoc>
public void DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped(Image image, Rectangle rect) {
    if(image == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("image");
    }

    int width = Math.Min(rect.Width, image.Width);
    int height = Math.Min(rect.Height, image.Height);

    //We could put centering logic here too for the case when the image is smaller than the rect
    DrawImage(image, rect, 0, 0, width, height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```

`DrawImage` and `DrawImageUnscaled` do not and then probably rescale the image based on its internal DPI setting, which Matt found out to be less than the default 96, which leads to stretching of the image:

```
/// <include file='doc\Graphics.uex' path='docs/doc[@for="Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled"]/*' />
/// <devdoc>
/// </devdoc>
public void DrawImageUnscaled(Image image, Point point) {
    DrawImage(image, point.X, point.Y);
}
```

Comment: It would appear that the backGround has a horizontal and vertical resolution of `96` whereas the PNG on disk has `71.9582` for some reason, so this would account for this difference

Comment: @MattWilko Ok, that is tricky to find. I was looking at the reference source for drawing the image. When using `DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped` the call in the .NET source specifically sets `GraphicsUnit` to `Pixel`, while the other methods don't. So there the DPI setting is ignored while the other methods probably use `Point` and therefore take the image DPI into account.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I think I will change my images to the same DPI for ease of use.