# Drawing images in picturebox are never precise

Tags: c#, picturebox, drawimage

[image]

Hi, I'm trying to draw an image of a region(with a yellow border) over my world map. my picturebox is exactly {Width=1431, Height=839}. it's ClientSize is exactly {Width=1431, Height=839}, the image is exactly {Width=1431, Height=839}. NO scaling going on here.

*(note I'm not using the PictureBox.Image Property)*

When I overlap both images in an editor(right) they fit perfectly.
When I overlap them(left) using:

```
Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.risk_map1431x839, 0, 0);
//similar method for smalle roverlapping image
```

they refuse to fit, it's definitely not a matter of positioning because you can clearly see they are a different size.

I have checked the files countless times and they are all the same!

I'm out of ideas, any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Is it possible that the files have different horizontal and vertical resolutions? In other words, do they have different DPI settings? If so, you might be having the same unusual problem as [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34879238/when-overlaying-two-identically-sized-images-one-is-offset), where `DrawImage` is scaling the image internally based on its DPI settings. The solution is to call `DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped`.

Comment: thanks, I'll look into it right now!

Comment: yes thank you! that did it!!
how do I mark it as solved?

Comment: I just marked this question as a duplicate of that one. Didn't want to do that unless it was your problem, though! Glad you got it sorted!